# Node.js with StatsD

Tags: javascript, node.js, statsd

I'm using etsy/statsd using the node.js.

I have created a config file too.

I'm starting statsD using: node node_modules/statsd/bin/statsd statsDConfig.js

To check I used: echo "foo:1|c" | nc -u -w0 127.0.0.1 8125

There is not much documentation how I could use it programatically.
I want to utilize statsd to get the API calls count to the facebook made through a script.

I have done following steps:

1. Installed statsD using "npm i statsd".
2. I have changed the backend to console.

I have bit knowledge about counters, sets, guages, etc.
But when I require it in node.js code using :

```
Var statsd = require('statsd');

var start = Date.now();
retun AuthSerrver.auth(req.headers)
.then(function() {})
.finally(function() {
var latency = Date.now() -start;
statsd.histogram('auth.latency_ms', latency);
});
```

It gives me error like: **"Error: Cannot find module 'statsd'"**
Whereas I can find the it in node_modules.

Any help on how to get it working would be appreciated. Any example would be a cherry on the cake.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you can do.

There is nothing wrong with the statsD installation.

Basically your syntax for using it is wrong.

I will share a slideshow that will guide you through the actual use of statsD.

You should check the [StatsD](http://rosskukulinski.github.io/talk-statsd/#/) docs.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I will try that